# String to byte array conversion in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, local-storage

I am developing an app in asp.net in which I am implementing image upload control when user upload the image, it stores into localstorgae and in local storage it saves in the form of string and I want to convert it into the bytes array so I can send it to the controller through ajax post in javascript file so tell me how it is possible or how can I convert it into the bytes array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you save the image as data url, which is base 64 encode. So you just need to send the string to the server and decode it with base 64.

Comment: Dear plz tell me how to decode it to base 64. plz give me the example code

Answer (score 0):

in .NET you would use the Encoding class to convert string to byte, depending on the encoding type, you might need to use UTF8 or ASCII.

```
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
bytes[] byteData = ascii.GetBytes("string");
```